# How can I dynamically add property from .cfg (OSGI) to persistence.xml (Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, osgi, jbossfuse

The following case:

in my **test_property.cfg** file i have the property line:

```
...
hibernate/persistence.schema=TEST_1
...
```

in the **persistence.xml** i have the setting line:

```
...
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="${hibernate/persistence.schema}" />
....
```

But after build the project the value ${hibernate/persistence.schema} - did not replaced

---

xml files where I use blueprint tag - is ok, but I try to find out how to use replaceable values for persistence.xml from test property.cfg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cfg** files are used only at **runtime** and not at build phase.

-At build phase you can resolve maven variables as you like by enabling ressources feltering on the folder containing your persistance.xml ([here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) is some useful documentation).

-At runtime, it is not possible to bind a property from cfg file to an xml other file. Don't forget that the bundle is already built so it is a jar which is immutable.

**My solution**:

-define a new bean that consume the property from cfg. Here we are sure that any changes in the cfg at runtime will be immediately detected.

-in that bean, read the xml file and override the wanted property from the one already read from cfg.

Comment: -thank you for response, yes this is right way of resolve the problem, also I want to add a couple of notes. - that will need to create own factory where you be able to choose which persistence.xml to use .. I didnt found any decision, only customize factory